# IOS UITabbarController set Image is not possible

Tags: ios, swift

Hello my Guys i have some Problems to set the image in the UITabbarController. I use the Interfacebuilder to do that. But when I start the Simulator the tabs don't even images. It would be very nice when you can help me.

[image]

Comment: could you show somthing more ? image or you tabbar in Interfacebuilder ? because the RGB channels of the image are completely ignored and you need to use the alpha channel exclusively.

Comment: I just uploaded an image you can check it

Comment: Looks like an image that does not use alpha. You can't have different colors in a UITabBar image.

Comment: maybe i use wrong pictures but i'm not sure...Is there some examples picture for UITabbarController ?

Comment: @BilalReffas try this http://makeapppie.com/2014/09/09/swift-swift-using-tab-bar-controllers-in-swift/

Comment: or http://jslim.net/blog/2014/05/05/ios-customize-uitabbar-appearance/

Comment: okay thank you very much it was the pictures..so i check out how i can realize it.

Comment: Are you running it on a non retina simulator? If so I don't think it will show the 64*64 image as its to big. Non retina aim for 32*32.

Comment: i use only retina yes sure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's better to get 10*10 size png images, and add it to your tab item, and then you will come to know what size you can use.

Comment: may be the image resolutions are making some noise, so please resize your images a much as low to appropriate to your requirement.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=icon+images+png&espv=2&biw=1917&bih=943&tbs=isz:ex,iszw:20,iszh:10&tbm=isch&source=lnt         //  try any one of the image from above link.